# Selfmade ordered List Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a WYSIWYG-Editor running, and as HTML doesn't support ordered lists with numbering, I'm currently trying to implement it myself with JS/jQuery. What I mean is, instead of

1. test
2. test

   1. test
   2. test

I need something like

1. test
2. test

2.1. test

2.2 test

So what I tried, is react to some keyevents (F1-F4) to build down to 4 layers (so 2.1.1.1 for example). And in general, I got it working. The code for it is the following:

```js
onKeydown: function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode >= 112 && e.keyCode <= 115) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 112) {
      firstlayercount++;
      secondlayercount = 0;
      thirdlayercount = 0;
      fourthlayercount = 0;
      $('#bemerkungenbox').summernote('code', $('#bemerkungen').val() + '<br/><h1 class="u1">' + firstlayercount + "</h1>");
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 113) {
      secondlayercount++;
      $('#bemerkungenbox').summernote('code', $('#bemerkungen').val() + '<br/><h2 class="u2">' + firstlayercount + "." + secondlayercount + "</h2>");
      thirdlayercount = 0;
      fourthlayercount = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 114) {
      thirdlayercount++;
      $('#bemerkungenbox').summernote('code', $('#bemerkungen').val() + '<br/><h3 class="u3">' + firstlayercount + "." + secondlayercount + "." + thirdlayercount + "</h3>");
      fourthlayercount = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 115) {
      fourthlayercount++;
      $('#bemerkungenbox').summernote('code', $('#bemerkungen').val() + '<br/><h4 class="u4">' + firstlayercount + "." + secondlayercount + "." + thirdlayercount + "." + fourthlayercount + "</h4>");
    }
  }
}
var firstlayercount = 0,
  secondlayercount = 0;
var thirdlayercount = 0,
  fourthlayercount = 0;
firstlayercount = $('.u1').filter(':last')[0].innerHTML;
secondlayercount = $('.u2').filter(':last')[0].innerHTML.split('.')[1];
thirdlayercount = $('.u3').filter(':last')[0].innerHTML.split('.')[2];
fourthlayercount = $('.u4').filter(':last')[0].innerHTML.split('.')[3];
```

So actually, I have 4 counters, one for every layer, when going for another "firstlayer", I reset all others, when going for a "secondlayer", I only delete counter for layer 3 and 4, and so on. I think you got what I mean.

Also, I implented, that when editing the thing in the editor (after reloading the page), the numbering is continued and not starts from 1 again (the thing outside of the `keydown`-function).

And now comes the part, when it gets interesting and quite hard, where maybe, my idea doesn't work anymore like that.

With the code I just created, I can only add a new point to the end of the text, so if I have

1. test
2. test

2.1 test

2.2 test

2.2.1 test

and so on, I could add 2.2.1.1 or 2.2.2 or 2.3 or 3. which works completely fine.

But what happens, if I notice, that between 2.1 and 2.2 I forgot a chapter, then I would need put another chapter between it, so I click there and press F2 and get

1. test
2. test

2.1 test

2.2 test

2.3 test

2.3.1 test

as result, so all numbering after that have to get increased as well (and also decreased, if I remove a chapter, of course).

Another thing to mention: I can't use the css counter thing for that, I definetely need so save it in the database with the correct formatting and with the correct numbering.

Any ideas what I could do?

**Edit:** [This](https://jsfiddle.net/y5ejtozu/) is a fiddle I created to clarify what I have and what I got.
Even though in my Editor, instead of the code generated I see the thing resulting of it (so the `h1` as heading, and so on), but this doesn't change anything on what needs to be done.

```js
var firstlayercount = 0,
  secondlayercount = 0;
var thirdlayercount = 0,
  fourthlayercount = 0;
$('#tarea').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode >= 112 && e.keyCode <= 115) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 112) {
      firstlayercount++;
      secondlayercount = 0;
      thirdlayercount = 0;
      fourthlayercount = 0;
      $('#tarea').val($('#tarea').val() + '<br/><h1 class="u1">' + firstlayercount + "</h1>");
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 113) {
      secondlayercount++;
      $('#tarea').val($('#tarea').val() + '<br/><h2 class="u2">' + firstlayercount + "." + secondlayercount + "</h2>");
      thirdlayercount = 0;
      fourthlayercount = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 114) {
      thirdlayercount++;
      $('#tarea').val($('#tarea').val() + '<br/><h3 class="u3">' + firstlayercount + "." + secondlayercount + "." + thirdlayercount + "</h3>");
      fourthlayercount = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 115) {
      fourthlayercount++;
      $('#tarea').val($('#tarea').val() + '<br/><h4 class="u4">' + firstlayercount + "." + secondlayercount + "." + thirdlayercount + "." + fourthlayercount + "</h4>");
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="100" rows="30" id="tarea"></textarea>
```

Here you can find the code directly here as well.

Comment: "as HTML doesn't support ordered lists with number"  Has someone used css to hide the numbers? as an ordered list should display numbering by default. Also css counters might help you  https://davidwalsh.name/css-counters

Comment: @LiamKenneth ofcourse, 1.test 2.test 3.test is working, but not 1.1.1 test and so on, also, as I mentioned, I can't work with css counters

Comment: @mplungjan working on it

Comment: @mplungjan done it, you can find a fiddle, as well as the code directly in my post